# How to send the user to different views

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am creating an application which will send the user to different views of the application, for that I am using Vue 3 and the Vue router, but I am having a problem when trying to show a different page this does not do it, as I understand it for Being able to show a page is necessary , but if I use it, the view will be shown below my components, one option is to create a conditional to show the view, or the components, but doing that seems like a very dirty way to do it. to do the things. 
This is my vue:

```
<template>
  <h2>Proyectos</h2>

  <div class="actions">
    <router-link to="/proyectos/crear" class="action__add">
      <i class="material-icons-outlined">
        add
      </i>
      Crear Proyecto
    </router-link>
    <input type="text" class="action__search" placeholder="Buscar..." />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content">
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import ListProject from '../../components/project/ListProject.vue';
export default {
  components: { ListProject },
};
</script>
```

This is my router:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/proyectos',
    name: 'Project',
    component: () => import('../views/project/AppContent.vue'),
    children : [
      {
        path: 'crear',
        component: () => import('../views/project/AppCreate.vue')
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

The  component I repeat it multiple times is just a practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move "grid-content" to a new component (e.g. GridContent.vue) and load it with the default child route.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/proyectos',
    name: 'Project',
    component: () => import('../views/project/AppContent.vue'),
    children : [
      { 
        path: '', 
        component: () => import('../views/project/GridContent.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'crear',
        component: () => import('../views/project/AppCreate.vue')
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

You can take a look at https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes

Sample code after moving the components:

```
<template>
  <h2>Proyectos</h2>

  <div class="actions">
    <router-link to="/proyectos/crear" class="action__add">
      <i class="material-icons-outlined">
        add
      </i>
      Crear Proyecto
    </router-link>
    <input type="text" class="action__search" placeholder="Buscar..." />
  </div>

  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import ListProject from '../../components/project/ListProject.vue';
export default {
  components: { ListProject },
};
</script>
```

Now `<router-view />` will render GridContent.vue on landing and render AppCreate.vue on route change to "/proyectos/crear"

Comment: That is to say that I have to divide my components, in views?

Comment: Yes. Divide the components in different views and make use of `router-view` to render the content on route change will be a much better option than using conditionals

Comment: Thank you very much, excuse the question, but creating a view where they will only work as components, could it cause code that cannot be understood in the future?

Comment: In fact views are not created. It is components being created and some of them act as views if they are used by routes. Structuring the app as different components actually make the code more readable and easier to manage, especially when later the app gets bigger and more components are introduced.